# Parsing and rendering JSON data in Java with GeoTools

Tags: java, geotools, json, rendering

I'm working on a Web Map Service written in Java and using the GeoTools library. My goal is to make the data parsing json format, so I'm using the [form Unsupported GeoTools](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/unsupported/geojson). This is the parsingJSON method that takes in the path of the input file and returns as output the FeatureCollection of the files feature:

```
public FeatureCollection parsingJSON(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {
        System.out.println("INTO PARSINGJSON");
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        File f = new File(path); 
        System.out.println("complete path file --->" + f.getAbsolutePath());

        Object obj = parser.parse(new java.io.FileReader(path));
        FeatureJSON fJSON = new FeatureJSON();
        FeatureCollection fc = fJSON.readFeatureCollection(obj.toString());
        return fc;
    }
```

When I run the code by passing the path of the file, gives me this exception:

```
mag 02, 2016 4:09:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet ServletWMS threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at com.lamiaservlet.servlets.ServletWMS.operation(ServletWMS.java:140)
    at com.lamiaservlet.servlets.ServletWMS.doGet(ServletWMS.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:612)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:503)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I want to clarify that I imported the library properly [json-simple-1.1](http://www.java2s.com/Cod) and I have the following pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>Servlet</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <geotools.version>13.2</geotools.version>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--   Third-party dependencies   -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-geojson</artifactId>
             <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I edited the question. The error is already present when I try to create, through the MarshallerTest class, Capabilities Document. The createLayer methods allow you to add the layers to the document

Comment: Please edit again to focus the question on the piece that is failing,  with the minimum of code to manifest the issue

Comment: your pom has no dependencies - see https://gist.github.com/ianturton/86c57ca1beea54b43ca8a3fc7467f9e2 for a  fuller example pom.xml

Comment: I modified the pom.xml file by entering the dependency, but there is the problem on " DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);"

Comment: Closed as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984674/java-servlet-parsing-geo-json-with-geotools which is a better place to discuss the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your error has nothing to do with JSON, there is a problem with the PostGIS datastore jar on your path. The most likely cause of this issue is that you have combined jars from different GeoTools releases. Check your pom.xml file - the usual practice is to use a property geotools.version set to the version you plan to use:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <geotools.version>15-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
  </properties>
```

and then in dependencies use that property to set the version:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
      <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-render</artifactId>
      <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I modified the pom.xml file by entering the dependency and properties. The problems persist!

Comment: Making this change, now nothing works any more!